# address cell in data.frame according to ID

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame in R. It looks like this (but is much larger):

```
df <- data.frame(A = rep(NULL, 5),
                 B = rep(NULL, 5),
                 ID = c(3,6,8,9,27))


> df
      A      B      ID
1     NULL   NULL    3
2     NULL   NULL    6
3     NULL   NULL    8
4     NULL   NULL    9
5     NULL   NULL   27
```

In order to write their corresponding value into each cell, I need to exactly adress each cell by their column name and the ID-value (column 3). So that X would be adressed by *column = A* and *ID = 8* in the following example. (Instead of *column = A* and *Row = 3*)

```
> df
      A      B      ID
1     NULL   NULL    3
2     NULL   NULL    6
3     X      NULL    8
4     NULL   NULL    9
5     NULL   NULL   27
```

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: It is better to have NA instead of NULL as string

Comment: Thank you for the comment. If it is easy to eyplain - why?

Comment: in R, `NULL` is an empty object whereas missing observations you would want to be represented by `NA`, representing something that doesn't exist. Something that doesn't exist != an empty object. Furthermore, `NA` can be coerced into other vector types very easily, and as it is a logical constant, there are many functions to help manipulate them.

Can you clarify what you mean by addressing X? Do you mean the indexed location?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think I understand. What I wanted to do: fill the NAs. I do know, for example, that variable A is 0.7 for ID 8. How do I tell R to assign `df[3,1]<-0.7` but using the ID instead of the row?

Comment: Perhaps I can do it the other way round: how can I ask R, in which Row ID=8?

Comment: `which(df$ID==8)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question appears to be rather simple but there are different aspects to be considered in an answer.

The OP has asked how to replace values in a certain column in rows which match a given `ID` value.

#### Data types

First you have to consider the types of data which are used for replacement. So, if `A` is to contain data of type numeric and `B` of type character, a sample data set can be created by

```
df <- data.frame(A = NA_real_,
                 B = NA_character_,
                 ID = c(3,6,8,9,27),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
```

> ```
>    A    B ID
> 1 NA <NA>  3
> 2 NA <NA>  6
> 3 NA <NA>  8
> 4 NA <NA>  9
> 5 NA <NA> 27
> ```

```
str(df)
```

> ```
> 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  3 variables:
>  $ A : num  NA NA NA NA NA
>  $ B : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ID: num  3 6 8 9 27
> ```

This will avoid costly type conversions. The parameter `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` will avoid errors due to wrong factor levels.

#### Base R

As mentioned [by dshkol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224330/address-cell-in-data-frame-according-to-id#comment79415560_46224330), `which(df$ID==8)` returns the row number(s). So, a complete answer would be:

```
df[which(df$ID == 8), "A"] <- 0.7
df
```

> ```
>     A    B ID
> 1  NA <NA>  3
> 2  NA <NA>  6
> 3 0.7 <NA>  8
> 4  NA <NA>  9
> 5  NA <NA> 27
> ```

#### Using `data.table`

The OP has mentioned that the production data frame is *much larger*. If there are many replacement operations on large data objects, it might be worthwhile to consider using `data.table` because these are done *in place* only in the affected rows, i.e., without copying the whole column. This will save time and memory.

In addition, the syntax is more concise.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df) # creating a copy of df for illustration
# replacement in place in rows given by row number
dt[which(ID == 8), A := 0.7][]
# replacement in place in rows given by condition
dt[ID == 8, A := 0.7][]
```

> ```
>      A  B ID
> 1:  NA NA  3
> 2:  NA NA  6
> 3: 0.7 NA  8
> 4:  NA NA  9
> 5:  NA NA 27
> ```

#### Using a keyed `data.table`

Setting a key on a data.table will further speed up the searching for a particular `ID` and the code will become even more concise:

```
setkey(dt, ID)
dt[.(8), A := 0.7][]
```

The output is the same as shown above.

#### Replacing multiple values at once using a lookup table

If there are many values to be replaced in one column, it might be more efficient to store them in a lookup table and use this in an *update on join* operation:

```
lookupA <- data.table(ID = c(8, 3), 
                      new = c(0.7, 1.2))
lookupA
```

> ```
>    ID new
> 1:  8 0.7
> 2:  3 1.2
> ```

```
dt[lookupA, on = "ID", A := new][]
```

> ```
>      A  B ID
> 1: 1.2 NA  3
> 2:  NA NA  6
> 3: 0.7 NA  8
> 4:  NA NA  9
> 5:  NA NA 27
> ```